# How to create optimal observation given a classifier

Tags: machine-learning, methodology, data-generating-process

Suppose that I have a dataset $D$ of cars and a classifier $C$ which, given two cars characteristics, predicts which car is "better". *(It's a binary classification, the definition of better is not important)*.

My problem is to find (create?) an observation $x^*$ such that for any $x$ in $D$, the probability that classifier $C$ says that $x^*$ is better than $x$ is maximal.

How can this be done ?

PS:

It seems similar to the approach using Generative Adversarial Networks in [Interpreting the Latent Space of GANs for Semantic Face Editing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10786) ([blog](https://yonigottesman.github.io/2020/11/17/wgan-controllable-generation.html/)).*(I suppose that in this case output for the classifier will be something like average of probabilities against all cars of my dataset)*

Is it the way to go ? Are there better/simpler methods ?

Comment: Is the classifier $C$ differentiable?

Comment: I guess so, since the output is a continuous probability. Is there another requirement?

Comment: This isn't about the output distribution though, but about the model itself, e.g. neural networks are differentiable, while decision trees (and derivatives thereof) are not.

Comment: We can consider it is differentiable.

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward optimization problem, so you can either use a black-box optimization algorithm (simulated annealing, genetic algorithms etc.), or use knowledge you have about the classifier to use a fine-tuned optimizer, e.g., some kind of Newton-Raphson. Or you can use an algorithm that approximates derivatives numerically. I don't think we can be more specific than that unless you explain what kind of classifier you have. (Note that the output may be a highly atypical instance, perhaps a car with 37 wheels with a mileage of 735.99 mpg. Constraints may be important.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa +1. Perhaps a generative model would be ideal here, if the goal is to get realistic samples from the original distribution.